# Ambiguous call to varargs method

Tags: java

If there are two methods

```
public void foo(Something... things){}
public void foo(Something thing){}
```

And the following call with a single argument is made

```
foo(something);
```

Which of the above methods will be called? Does the order the above methods are declared in matter?

The reason I would have such method is to implement a for each loop in the varargs method which calls the single arguments method in the loop.

Comment: The second method is called. Specific methods are always preferred over varargs methods.

Comment: If you're just iterating though the varargs and calling the single method, there's not much use for the single method. The performance drawback from creating a singleton loop is negligible if not non-existent.

Comment: It may not be obvious first time looking at the code but if doing `do(something);` did indeed call the varargs version, how would we ever call the non-varargs version?